# Elementary Geometrical Proofs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

How do you prove two lines are perpendicular to each other? and then how do you prove that lines ABCD are quadrilateral, or any other specified shape?

Is their like a database of certain things you need to mention when proving such things? Do you have to recall certain given properties, etc?

In proofs, is their only ONE way to set out your answer?

[image]

Comment: "The essence of mathematics lies in its freedom"- George Cantor.

Comment: There are many ways, for example for perpendicular you can use Thales' theorem (possibly together with Pythagoras) or the fact that diagonals in a rhombus are perpendicular or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is very rarely only *one* way to prove things (I believe the official count of different proofs of the Pythagorean theorem is around 400, and even Euclid himself supplies two different proofs in his Elements).

How many things you need to mention in the course of a proof (that is, what results you can just accept as fact) are more or less up to you, or whoever is correcting you. A friend of mine from my days in competitions was told by our coach that "you don't write down enough trivial things", so it's definitely possible to be too brief, even for mathematicians with experience. But a proof of something like the angle bisector theorem shouldn't be four pages long. You have to find a comfortable spot in between, and that can only be done through experience.

As to your specific problems (showing that two lines are perpendicular, for instance), how to prove them very much depends on the problem. It wouldn't surprise me if there were many geometry problems from the big international competitions where that was exactly the task, and which requires several pages to finally prove. On the other hand, it might be as easy as quoting the Pythagorean theorem. It depends solely on the information you have available.

Comment: I have provided a relevant example question (b)

Comment: @Oistulate In your example question, if you have proved (a), then the easiest way is in my opinion to say that $\angle OBA \cong \angle OBC$, and together they make $180^\circ$, therefore they must be right angles. But there are other ways. Since $B$ is on the middle of the chord, it is at the point closest to $O$. Therefore they are perpendicular. You could also set it into coordinate systems and prove that $\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{OB} = 0$, or calculate the lengths in the picture using for instance the angle $\angle AOB$ as a free variable, and quote the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 1):

> *In proofs, is their only ONE way to set out your answer?*

Thankfully, no. Otherwise mathematics would be a robotic litany of things from the database, and not the creative form that it is.

The biggest tragedy is that some people *do* believe it is a litany and *don't* believe there is a creative aspect.

To get back to your question, there is usually more than one way to get from hypotheses to conclusion. When this is the case, each path may reveal something slightly different about the problem. You cannot "prove everything with this one weird tip."

The best answer will depend on the statement of your problem.

Comment: I have provided a sample problem (b)